# error while loadin applet in web application

Tags: applet

I want to run my applet on web application, but i got some error which i mentioned below please help me to get out of this problem

```
Java Plug-in 1.7.0
Using JRE version 1.7.0-ea-b116 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\HONEY
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------


java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mp3$1
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mp3$1
 at mp3.<init>(mp3.java:93)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$12.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mp3$1
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 ... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed:http://viscous10.webng.com/mp3/mp3$1.class
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getBytes(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 ... 21 more
Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mp3$1
```

but it happens only if i run applet with events
and in simple applet i never occurred

Comment: Why are you using an early-access version of Java7?  Just use Java6, it's more likely to work.

Comment: Looks like, the runtime dependent libraries are not listed in classpath or applet(jnlp) lib tags. The simple applet would not go into use the libraries(mp3 related?) when running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means the Java runtime cannot find the .class file for an anonymous inner class of your mp3 class. Anonymous inner classes are named OuterClass$1, OuterClass$2, OuterClass$3 and so on. An example of the definition of an anonymous inner class:

```
  button1.addActionListener(
     new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
     {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e)
        {
           // do something
        }
     }
  );
```

As it seems you are using inner classes, be aware that your mp3.java source file creates various .class files and make sure all of these .class files are available for the runtime environment (via copying, or adding them in a .jar file, etc).

Comment: thank you so much for your cordial attention i will try it but one problem is occurs while creating jar file "java exception occurred" thats why i have added zip file is it sounds correct or not

Answer (score 0):

to run the applet on web browser

1. write java code run the application on java
2. make the class file by using cmd prompt
3. give proper path and run your java file on cmd prompt to create class file
4. make html file add applet code in it `<applet code=file.class archive =file.zip/jar></applet>`
5. enabled java console from control panel
6. run the html file and refresh the window

NOTE: make sure class file, html file,zip or jar file having same name for avoiding any confusion